# Place layer content at the center

Tags: html, css

I want to place text using div layers this way:

[image]

I tried this:

```
<div style="display: table; margin: 0 auto; padding-bottom: 15px;">
    <!-- mail layer with centered content -->main text
</div>



<div style="position: relative; float:right; padding-left: 15px;">
     <!-- second layer with right content -->left text
</div>

<div style="position: relative; float:right; padding-left: 15px; padding-top: 2px;">
<!-- mail layer with right content -->left text
</div>
```

But the text is not placed like the picture. Is there any better solution?

Answer (score 1):

It depends on how you want your text to act when it gets longer.

1. You could either put the center text in `absolute` position like this : https://jsfiddle.net/jh43ezek/
2. Or put the left items in a div in `absolute` position : https://jsfiddle.net/jh43ezek/1/

Hope that'll help !

Answer (score 1):

How about doing it like this? https://jsfiddle.net/DIRTY_SMITH/eu6x72zf/2/

html

```
<div class="wrapper">
<div class="div3">
<!-- mail layer with right content -->left text
</div>
<div class="div2">
     <!-- second layer with right content -->left text
</div>
<div class="div1">
    <!-- mail layer with centered content -->main text
</div>
</div>
```

Css

```
body{margin: 0;}
.wrapper{width: 100%; background-color: yellow}
.div1{ width: 100px; margin: 0 auto; display: block; padding-bottom: 15px;}
.div2, .div3{float:right; padding-left: 15px;}
```